# How to change Filamentphp Heroicon version?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-filament, heroicons

Filamentphp is using `Heroicon v1` as it says in [the documentation](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/resources/getting-started#icons).

But I wanted to change the version to v2. It wasn't successful.

I installed the `blade-ui-kit/blade-heroicons` package and required it. Then I updated the composer.

```json
"require": {
   "blade-ui-kit/blade-heroicons": "^1.2|^2.10",
}
```

The reason why I put `^1.2|^2.10` instead of `^2.10` for the version is that it had given me an error:

```
Problem 1
    - filament/forms[v2.16.0, ..., 2.x-dev] require blade-ui-kit/blade-heroicons ^1.2 -> found blade-ui-kit/blade-heroicons[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.3.1] but it conflicts with your root
```

It doesn't give me this error now when I changed the version like I said, but it still isn't working and I can't use `Heroicon v2` icons in Filamentphp.

Comment: https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/issues/3916

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently being worked on for Filament v3. As of today, it is not supported since `blade-ui-kit/blade-heroicons` dropped support for Laravel 8.

[Source](https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/issues/3916)